# What is the origin of the 'typical' alien?

Tags: aliens, history-of, science-fiction-genre

When most people (well, probably not people from this site, but the general public) think of an alien, they probably think of an alien in the general form like below:

[image: the 'typical' alien]

This sort of alien has the large round eyes, round face, fairly thin.

I'm wondering **what is the first piece of science fiction to describe aliens like this** and **is this where this stereotype originated from, or was it from somewhere else?**